# how to remove div if window is smaller then 600px

Tags: html

do you know how to remove div when it´s inside of another div? I need to remove div "2" and this isn´t working:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) 
{
    #zmiz { display:none; }
}

<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="fwImage col span_6">
        <div class="ahoj" style="position: absolute; width: 80%;">
            <div class="col span_4 logo_shift" style="line-height: 21px; ">
                <h1>Certifikát</h1>
                <p>)ily <a href="#image-7">linde</a>.Yo.</p>
                <p>Sc.</p>
                <p>St <a href="http://www.fl.com">Gic</a>, ad.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="gallery-t-group" class="royalSlider rsDefaultInv">
            <div id="zmiz">
                <a class="rsImg" href="gal/blank.png"><img class="rsTmb" width="56" height="56"src="gal/p.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <a class="rsImg" href="gal/certifikat1.jpg"><img class="rsTmb" width="56" height="56"src="gal/certifikat2.jpg" /></a>
            <a class="rsImg" href="../img/full-width/medium/2.jpg"><img class="rsTmb" width="56" height="56" src="gal/kabel.jpg" /></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: ID definitions are not allowed to start with a number. Maybe that's your issue? [http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/](http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)

Comment: I know, it was just example... but it isnt working

Comment: Hi, creator of that slider told me this: If you wish to remove slide by hiding it - it won't work, you should use JS for this. Do you know, how should that js look like?

Answer (score 3):

Your id must start with a letter (at least for this CSS problem, even if theoretically in HTML5 it's not mandatory). It works if you fix that :

```
<div id="a1" class="1_5">
<div id="a2">
  <a class="2_5" href="a.png"><img class="3" width="1" height="2" src="b.png" />AAA</a>
</div>
</div>

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
#a2 {display:none;}
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ehuker/1/edit

Note that even if now [HTML5 ids are supposed to be less constrained](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id), there are still many tools, old browsers, and so on which don't work well if you don't follow the old HTML4 naming rules.

Comment: At least fix `#1` as well. :)

Comment: My ids aren´t really numbers they are just text, but on my page html page it´s not working for some reason...

Comment: Hard to guess why it doesn't work in your case without your code.

Comment: Hi, creator of that slider told me this: If you wish to remove slide by hiding it - it won't work, you should use JS for this. Do you know, how should that js look like?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This answer addressed a sample code snippet which had `div id="2"`.**

Dystroy's answer is correct: by specification an ID cannot start with a number; but if for some reason you can't change the ID (maybe all your JavaScript is dependent on it or something), this workaround does work:

```
CSS
---
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    [id='2'] {
        display: none;
    }
}

HTML
----
<div id="a1" class="1_5">
    <div id="a2">
        <a class="2_5" href="a.png"><img class="3" width="1" height="2" src="b.png" />AAA</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/yeHZT/) (drag the 'result' section wider to see the div appear).

Comment: My ids aren´t really numbers they are just text, but on my page html page it´s not working for some reason...

Comment: Hi, creator of that slider told me this: If you wish to remove slide by hiding it - it won't work, you should use JS for this. Do you know, how should that js look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your code [works on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUTpn/). Also, tidied it up for you:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="fwImage col span_6">
        <div class="ahoj" style="position: absolute; width: 80%;">
            <div class="col span_4 logo_shift" style="line-height: 21px; ">
                <h1>Certifikát</h1>
                <p>)ily <a href="#image-7">linde</a>.Yo.</p>
                <p>Sc.</p>
                <p>St <a href="http://www.fl.com">Gic</a>, ad.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="gallery-t-group" class="royalSlider rsDefaultInv">
            <div id="zmiz">
                <a class="rsImg" href="gal/blank.png"><img class="rsTmb" width="56" height="56"src="gal/p.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <a class="rsImg" href="gal/certifikat1.jpg"><img class="rsTmb" width="56" height="56"src="gal/certifikat2.jpg" /></a>
            <a class="rsImg" href="../img/full-width/medium/2.jpg"><img class="rsTmb" width="56" height="56" src="gal/kabel.jpg" /></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Most likely, what's happening is you're overwriting this `display:none;` rule somewhere else in your CSS or your JavaScript.

If you post a link to your code, or your full code and full CSS, I will take a look.

Comment: Your `zmiz DIV` does hide when width is less than 600. Something in your JS is creating a `DIV` on top of it. I suggest using Firebug to debug this as I don't have time to go through all the JS, but your CSS rule is working.

Comment: Hi, creator of that slider told me this: If you wish to remove slide by hiding it - it won't work, you should use JS for this. Do you know, how should that js look like?